# How do you override inline onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

This seems deceptively simple.

How do you override the onclick event in the following HTML using JavaScript?

```
<a id="sample" href="..." onclick="alert('hello world')" />...</a>
```

I've tried it with jQuery, but that didn't do the trick:

```
$('#sample').attr('onclick','alert("done")')
```

Assume the HTML is pre-written and cannot be changed, other than manipulating it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Setting the DOM element's onclick to null removes 
// the inline click handler
$("#sample")[0].onclick = null;
$("#sample").click(function() { alert("done") });
```

Comment: That was non-obvious, and it worked. Thanks Andrew. Why the [0]?

Comment: @Diodeus: jQuery objects, much like DOM collections or arrays, have numerical indexes for each contained element. `[0]` will fetch the first matched element of the selector.

Comment: I would assume since I'm selecting by ID that it would be unique and never result in an array. Sometimes what seems logical is....wrong.

Comment: Further to this method, as in my case, if you are matching on more than one element, you could do `$('.datacell').each(function() {this.onclick = $.noop;});` to silence all the `onclick`'s

Comment: @Diodeus "I would assume since I'm selecting by ID that it would be unique" => the point of [0] in this specific case is not to restrict the selection but rather to convert the format from jQuery object to DOM element

Answer (score 9):

This can also be done without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("sample").setAttribute('onclick','alert("done")');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<a id="sample" href="..." onclick="alert('hello world'); return false;" />...</a>
```

Or

```
$('#sample').attr('onclick','alert("done"); return false;')
```

Despite being able to set the `return false;` either directly in the onclick or by using jQuery, it doesn't actually require jQuery to be used at all. The benefit is if for whatever reason your jQuery script leads to a `404`, your code will still work.

I found the answer [here](http://www.bradino.com/javascript/onclick-return-false/).

Comment: Oh balls, I think I've completely misunderstood your question! Sorry dude :S

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("sample").onclick = $.noop;

$.noop == function(){};
```

[jQuery noop](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/)

Comment: `$("#sample")[0].onclick = null;` and `document.getElementById("sample").onclick = $.noop;` are nearly identical. how can you say that this did not work?

Comment: I tested this and found that it works for my purposes (I did not test to see if it overrides attribute, but it probably does)