# event.preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had button which had onclick function

```
<div id="canvas">   
  <button onclick="document.location.href='hello.php'">Go</button>
</div>
```

Now I want to stop this `onclick` event which redirects to `hello.php`, so I have written the following jQuery function

```
$("#canvas").on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This didn't work so I added a `return false` but it's still not working.

```
$("#canvas").on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

You can view it at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88ke2g4c/2/)

**Note: I do not want to remove onclick of button**

Comment: why can't you remove the `onclick` ?

Comment: Yeah...you should definitely just remove the `onclick` from your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you override inline onclick event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629916/how-do-you-override-inline-onclick-event)

Comment: My guess is he can't, it could be being added by a third party script.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Are you unable to amend the html?

Comment: Can't we get it with out removing onclick

Comment: @Manohar: Do you mean without removing it from the HTML, or without removing it [as in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31814351/157247)?

Comment: @Manohar: If you only wanted to disable it under certain circumstances, you can get the `.onclick` property, remove the function but store it, and then invoke it from the handler you bound with jQuery as needed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder without removing from the HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct solution is to remove the `onclick` from the HTML in the first place.

Assuming that's not possible, you can remove it after the fact:

```
$("#canvas button").first().prop("onclick", null);
```

That clears the `onclick` property on the element, which removes the handler set up by the `onclick` attribute. (It's a no-op if the button doesn't exist at all.)

It's probably worth noting that if the `button` is in a form, it will now submit the form, since its `onclick` isn't taking the user away from the page. (Since `button`'s default `type` is `submit`.)

Answer (score 2):

You should just use the `removeAttr` jQuery method:

```
$('#canvas button').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Appreciate the feedback. It works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome (https://jsfiddle.net/kvwr2ds0/), though I can't test in IE at the moment. You are correct, that would remove inline onclick handlers from all `<button>` s of the parent `#canvas` container.

Comment: @RobM.: If you saw my earlier comment about IE11, disregard. Second time I tried it, it worked, even with jQuery 2.x. (Weird.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ha, I did see that but then thought I might have been hallucinating.

Comment: Just for anyone else reading here, this doesn't seem to be working at the moment with IE11 and jQuery 3.1.1. TJ Crowder's solution, however, does work.